# Putting Array with same values into another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have one big array which has a load of similar values but I want to put all the arrays with the same value into another array. For example, I have this array.

```
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(8) {
       ["symbol"]=>
        string(3) "aaaa"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "aaaa"
        ["buy_price"]=>
        string(14) "100.0000000000"
        ["current_worth"]=>
        string(14) "100.2500000000"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(8) {
       ["symbol"]=>
        string(3) "aaa"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "aaaaa"
        ["buy_price"]=>
        string(14) "100.0000000000"
        ["current_worth"]=>
        string(14) "100.2500000000"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(8) {
       ["symbol"]=>
        string(3) "xxx"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "xxxxx"
        ["buy_price"]=>
        string(14) "100.0000000000"
        ["current_worth"]=>
        string(14) "100.2500000000"
      }
   }
```

I want to be able run this array through a foreach loop and then output the array results together that all have the same name. Like too

- Name aaa
  -- Name aaa [0]
  -- Name aaa [1]
- Name xxx
  -- Name xxx [0]

I am struggling how to do the logic.

Comment: Please share you expected output as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - How to merge arrays inside array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041278/php-how-to-merge-arrays-inside-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need some reducing. Assuming that `$origin_array` contain what you need to transform:

```
$result = array_reduce($origin_array, function ($carry, $item) {
    $name = $item['name'];
    $carry[$name][] = $item;
    return $carry;
}, []);
```

This code will make 2-dimensional array where elements grouped by `name` field of origin array.

### Explanation

The best explanation will be to write analogical `foreach` loop:

```
$my_reduce = function ($carry, $item) { // callback, 2-nd param
    $name = $item['name'];
    $carry[$name][] = $item;
    return $carry;
};

$result = []; // initial value, 3 param

foreach($origin_array as $item) {
    $result = $my_reduce($result, $item);
}
```

This is roughly speaking what happens under the hood of [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! 

Are you able to just give a little description on what is happening in the code so I can understand better how it works :)

Comment: I tryed =) After all documentation of used function should be the best explanation