# merge two array values

Tags: php, arrays

How can I make this array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3412341233214
        [number] => 21000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12121212121212
        [number] => 18000
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12121212121212
        [number] => 17000
    )
)
```

Look like the one below, where [1] and [2] have been merged into a single array based on having the same `id` and the `number` has been added together.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3412341233214
        [number] => 21000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12121212121212
        [number] => 35000
    )
)
```

Comment: What do you have so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - How to merge arrays inside array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041278/php-how-to-merge-arrays-inside-array)

Comment: `$merged = array_merge($result[0], $result[1], .... $result[n]);`

Answer (score 0):

Create a `$tmp` array the store the `number` property in it.

Only store it if the `id` doesn't exist yet using:

```
if(!isset($tmp[$obj['id']]))
```

To make each value *unique*

After that, count the `$tmp` number with the `$array` number.

```
$tmp[$obj['id']]['number'] += $obj['number'];
```

**https://3v4l.org/UMJ4p**

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        "id" => 3412341233214,
        "number" => 21000    
    ),
    1 => array(
        "id" => 12121212121212,
        "number" => 18000    
    ),
    2 => array(
        "id" => 12121212121212,
        "number" => 17000    
    )
);

$tmp = Array();

foreach($array as $obj) {
    if(!isset($tmp[$obj['id']])) {
        $tmp[$obj['id']] = array_merge(Array('number'=>1),$obj);
        continue;
    }
    $tmp[$obj['id']]['number'] += $obj['number'];
}

print_r(array_values($tmp));
```

***The following code results into***

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => 21000
            [id] => 3412341233214
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [number] => 35000
            [id] => 12121212121212
        )

)
```