# Merging and array of arrays with the same keys

Tags: php, array-merge

So I found an answer which is supposed to work, however it doesn't appear too...

[Already accepted answer with the same issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041278/php-how-to-merge-arrays-inside-array)

I have got the following array called `$banners`:

```
[
  0 => [
    "bannerCustomTemplate" => 0,
    "bannerId" => 1,
    "bannerType" => 1,
    "bannerTitle" => "Merry",
    "bannerStrapline" => "Christmas",
    "bannerPeriod" => "2018-12-01 to 2018-12-10",
    "bannerText" => "Christmas opening hours"
  ],
  1 => [
    "bannerCustomTemplate" => 0,
    "bannerId" => 7,
    "bannerType" => 2,
    "bannerTitle" => "Easter",
    "bannerStrapline" => "Test",
    "bannerPeriod" => "2018-12-04 to 2018-12-12",
    "bannerText" => "dsadasdaas"
  ]
]
```

The answers I have read suggest `$all_banners = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $banners);`.

However this is giving me:

```
[
  "bannerCustomTemplate" => 0,
  "bannerId" => 7,
  "bannerType" => 2,
  "bannerTitle" => "Easter",
  "bannerStrapline" => "Test",
  "bannerPeriod" => "2018-12-04 to 2018-12-12",
  "bannerText" => "dsadasdaas"
]
```

Seems like it's just replacing rather than merging. Anyone got any ideas?

**Edit**

Just read the following comment

> Little note here. The updated variant with unpacking array doesn't work with string keys. But the first one works perfect. Just keep in mind this. – Alliswell

So I have now updated my code with another solutions, with the same results.

**Edit 2**

Well, merging is **merging** not replacing. So what I expect is:

```
[
    "bannerCustomTemplate" => [ 0, 0 ],
    "bannerId" => [ 1, 7 ],
    "bannerType" => [ 1, 2 ],
    "bannerTitle" => [ "Merry", "Easter" ]
    "bannerStrapline" => [ "Christmas", "Test" ]
    "bannerPeriod" => [ "2018-12-01 to 2018-12-10", "2018-12-04 to 2018-12-12" ]
    "bannerText" => ["Christmas opening hours", "dsadasdaas" ]
]
```

Comment: There's no simple built-in PHP function that would know to merge the values of identical keys into arrays of values. You'll need to do a bit more custom coding there. Also, the result should be an array of one array…!?

Comment: Is this answer approved falsely? It's the exact same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041278/php-how-to-merge-arrays-inside-array

Comment: Yeah, seems not fit for the question.

Comment: Sorry can you clarify. The above linked question was attempting to do the exact same thing as me, and he accepted the answer. Would that answer not have worked?

Comment: As I said: That answer indeed does not seem to fit the question. It would not have worked.

Comment: You could greatly improve this question by telling us specifically what you expect as output. Pointing to another page is not enough; questions should be self-contained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your arrays are known to contain the same keys in the same order, this is probably easiest:

```
$data = [
    ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 42],
    ['foo' => 'baz', 'baz' => 69]
];

$result = array_combine(array_keys($data[0]), array_map(null, ...$data));
```

This uses the useful behaviour of [`array_map` with `null` as the callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#example-6182) to take one element from each input array and return a new combined array.