# Can someone explain why array_merge() won't merge these two seemingly identical arrays?

Tags: php

I have the below snippet of code and I can't figure out why these two arrays won't merge - likely due to not understanding 100% how array_merge works. I'm expecting to see the duplicate, and merge the two into a single key. Running `array_unique` results in errors. Any ideas, or possibly an alternate solution to merge these two?

```
$a['12345']['label']    = '12345';
$a['12345']['type']     = 'Newspaper';

$b['12345']['label']    = '12345';
$b['12345']['type']     = 'Newspaper';

$result = array_merge($a, $b);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Array merge can't do duplicates. You have the same keys, so one set of data must overwrite another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

The short answer is that the merge is occurring, just not in the way you desire.

Comment: Explanation of array_merge and possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929642/php-array-merge-with-numerical-keys

Comment: Perfect, this resolves it. Also @jbrya029 thanks for that link, that `+` operator successfully merged them

Answer (score 0):

Because they would have the same keys. Try changing $b['12345'] to $b['12346'] and see if they merge.